# I want to collect all the particular object from nested object array object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want to collect all the object of a particular category from the nested array-object data in to one single array

```
let categoriesxy= [
        {
            catid: 'category-1',
            product: [
                {
                    id : 1,
                    name: 'sparrow'
                },
                {
                    id : 2,
                    name: 'parrot',
                }
            ]

        },
        {
            catid: 'category-2',
            product: [
                {
                    id : 1,
                    name: 'elephant',
                },
                {
                    id : 2,
                    name: 'horse',
                },
                {
                    id : 3,
                    name: 'lion',
                },
                {
                    id : 4,
                    name: 'tiger',
                }
            ]
        },
    ];
```

i want to store data inside product in to one array like xys = [ { id , name }, { id , name }... so on  ]
so i can call it like xyz.id, xyz.name etc

Comment: You can loop it through using map or forEach. and push into another array.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far as a text-based [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using flatmap

```js
let categoriesxy= [
    {
        catid: 'category-1',
        product: [
            {
                id : 1,
                name: 'sparrow'
            },
            {
                id : 2,
                name: 'parrot',
            }
        ]

    },
    {
        catid: 'category-2',
        product: [
            {
                id : 1,
                name: 'elephant',
            },
            {
                id : 2,
                name: 'horse',
            },
            {
                id : 3,
                name: 'lion',
            },
            {
                id : 4,
                name: 'tiger',
            }
        ]
    },
];

let ans = categoriesxy.flatMap(({product}) => [...product])
console.log({ans})
```

Comment: this answer is more efficient than use `map` and `flat` separately. and in your answer you don't need to use `spread` operator in `flatMap`

Answer (score 1):

you can can using `map` and `flat` methods

```js
let categoriesxy= [
        {
            catid: 'category-1',
            product: [
                {
                    id : 1,
                    name: 'sparrow'
                },
                {
                    id : 2,
                    name: 'parrot',
                }
            ]

        },
        {
            catid: 'category-2',
            product: [
                {
                    id : 1,
                    name: 'elephant',
                },
                {
                    id : 2,
                    name: 'horse',
                },
                {
                    id : 3,
                    name: 'lion',
                },
                {
                    id : 4,
                    name: 'tiger',
                }
            ]
        },
    ];
    
    let products = categoriesxy.map((item)=> item.product).flat()
    console.log(products)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to also keep the category for each product you can do it like:

```js
const categoriesxy = [ /* your list */ ]

const products = []
categoriesxy.forEach((category) => {
  category.product.forEach((product) => {
    products.push({ ...product, catid: category.catid })
  }
})
```

Comment: ur ans is correct but u have made typo error plz edit it

Comment: I see more optimized and shorter answers below, its the boring answer that got verified

Comment: @asma seems like he also wanted the catid to be present. Otherwise map + flat is a better option